# Send email from Drupal with HTML formatting

Tags: 9

I want to send a simple email from a custom module in Drupal 9 that contains a link, some break tags and a strong tag.

I used the default mail plugin in core to successfully send the email, but despite changing the mail headers to text/html, the MailManager plugin ultimately strips HTML out before sending the email.

There are several solutions listed for Drupal 9, I don't need bells and whistles for emails (templates, themes, stylesheets, etc). Whats the easiest way to allow me to send HTML emails?

Note: SwiftMailer is marked obsolete and its successor is tagged alpha with a healthy bug list.

Comment: My personal preferred solution is the Easy Email module (http://dgo.to/easy_email)

Comment: I moved from Swiftmailer to [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) when I went from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 and I didn't find it "complicated" to use...

Comment: I think this is because HTML Mail had a bug. Will post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send a HTML email?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297090/how-can-i-send-a-html-email)